# Using "as" vs "for" in comparisons

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> Having the pack of dogs **for** the soldiers, the broken glass pieces **for** the thorny fence, your house is well protected from intruders.

Is this sentence correct? I am not looking for a rewrite of the sentence; I am wishing to know if this sentence is grammatical.

Can the same sentence be written with **as** in place of **for** and yet, retain the meaning of the sentence? would it be wrong?

> Having the pack of dogs **as** the soldiers, the broken glass pieces **as** the thorny fence, your house is well protected from intruders.

Comment: **Having the dogs for the soldiers** would mean for their use. **As the soldiers** would mean **acting as**, which is your probable meaning.

Comment: So is it wrong to use for in such instances? I have read sentences with comparisons using "for"

Comment: This reminds me of the hymn [Hail to the Lord's Anointed](https://hymnary.org/text/hail_to_the_lords_anointed), which contains the line _To give them songs for sighing_. This used to puzzle me when I was young, because I interpreted it as 'songs to sigh'. Later I realised that it means 'songs _instead of_ sighing'. The hymn was written in 1821 - I think many people nowadays would be puzzled by _for the thorny fence_ and not realise that _for_ means _instead of_ or _acting as_.

Answer (score 0):

The analogy in the example is unusual. But I think it makes use of an idiom of the form "*have* X *for* Y", where X and Y are noun phrases, and Y specifies a role filled by X.

There is a similar question about [*have you **for/as** a friend*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lucky-to-have-you-for-a-friend-lucky-for-having-you-as-a-friend.3584760/).

In many of the examples I can find on the web (though not in the original example), X is an indefinite noun phrase denoting a negative characterization: [*have shit for brains*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=have+shit+for+brains); *have an alcoholic for a father*; [*If you are your own lawyer you have a fool for a client*](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2019/07/30/lawyer/).

"As" makes more literal sense, but it is perhaps less idiomatic with "have".

Answer (score 0):

> Having the pack of dogs **for/as** the soldiers [and] the broken glass pieces **for/as** the thorny fence, your house is well protected from intruders.

I have replaced the first comma with a conjunction.

'Having the pack of dogs for the soldiers' would mean the house owner has soldiers guarding his house, and the soldiers are further assisted by the dogs.  This is possible for a high security house.

'Having the pack of dogs as soldiers' would mean the dogs guard the house as if they were soldiers.
I have deleted the article before soldiers.  This is possible.

'Having broken glass pieces for the thorny fence' would mean supplementing the [thorny fence with broken glass pieces](https://images.app.goo.gl/Kkb7dea3W5wH2Q3x7).  This is possible.

'Having broken glass pieces as **a** thorny fence' would mean installing and using broken glass pieces as if they were a thorny fence.  Even with the use of the indefinite article before thorny, I am not sure if this is possible as I cannot visualise how broken glass pieces alone can look like a thorny fence.

Using the definite article before thorny would be less likely as the definite article means there is indeed already a fence.